# Passing more values under same prop name and test it with Jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, mobx

I am using Jest and Enzyme to test my React-Mobx app. I have come to a problem where I am accessing different values under the same prop name. As you can see I am accessing different properties under the same FilterssAction prop name.

```
@inject('RootStore', 'FiltersAction')
@observer
class ExpenseListFilters extends Component {
  state = {
    calendarFocused: null
  }

  onDatesChange = ({startDate, endDate}) => {
    this.props.FiltersAction.setStartDate(startDate)
    this.props.FiltersAction.setEndDate(endDate)
  }

  onTextChange = (e) => {
    this.props.FiltersAction.setTextFilter(e.target.value)
  }

...
```

When I write my test it fails. I need to pass props to shallow rendered component. So I am passing different values under same. This is not working, I keep getting an error TypeError: _this.props.FiltersAction.setTextFilter is not a function
How do I test this?

```
let setStartDateSpy, setEndDateSpy, setTextFilterSpy, sortByDateSpy, sortByAmountSpy, FiltersStore, wrapper

beforeEach(() => {
  setStartDateSpy = {setStartDate: jest.fn()}
  setEndDateSpy = {setEndDate: jest.fn()}
  setTextFilterSpy = {setTextFilter: jest.fn()}

  FiltersStore = {FiltersStore: {filters: filters}}

  wrapper = shallow(
    <ExpenseListFilters.wrappedComponent 
      FiltersAction = { 
        setStartDateSpy,
        setEndDateSpy,
        setTextFilterSpy
      }
      RootStore = {FiltersStore}
    />
  )
})

test('should handle text change', () => {
  const value = 'rent'
  wrapper.find('input').at(0).simulate('change', {
    target: {value}
  })
  expect(setTextFilterSpy).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(value)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your component is expecting `FiltersAction` to be an object whose values are functions.

In your application code, you can see that it as accessing the `FiltersActions` prop with [dot-notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors), and executing it as a function. For example, `this.props.FiltersAction.setEndDate(endDate)`

To pass a prop as an object, you need to wrap it again with curly braces. So, in your test, try passing FiltersAction as an object like below:

```
  wrapper = shallow(
    <ExpenseListFilters.wrappedComponent 
      FiltersAction = {{ 
        setStartDate: setStartDateSpy,
        setDentDate: setEndDateSpy,
        setTextFilter: setTextFilterSpy
      }}
      RootStore = {FiltersStore}
    />
  )
```

Note that in your example, you were:

1. Not double-wrapping your object w/ curly braces
2. Creating the object literal with computed property keys. That is, when you don't explicitly provide a property name, the resulting object will create the property name based on the variable name. [Here is a good resource for learning more about enhanced object literals in ES6](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/) So your generated object did not include the properties your application code was expecting and was attempting to call `undefined` as a function

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I tried that too. I get the same error because I can only set the props the same way I set them in my example.

Comment: Hmm - can you try passing `FiltersAction` as an object like `FiltersAction = {{setTextFilter: setTextFilterSpy, ...}} and so on?

Comment: omg, that worked. rearranging it a bit like this, setTextFilterSpy = jest.fn(),
`FiltersAction = {{setTextFilter: setTextFilterSpy, ...}} but the important part was to put it all in object. Can you plase make an answer for this and explain it a bit in details so I can accept you answer as a solution. Thanks for the help.